# с# winforms показать дату изменения данных

Tags: c#

уважаемые люди, есть приложение на winforms с базой данных отображаемых на датагриде , пользователь вводить какие-то данные в базу данных ,нужно фиксировать дату ввода или изменения данных допустим в Label или в текстбокс, разницы нету, помогите пожалуйста как это реализовать

Comment: фиксация обычно производится на уровне базы, добавьте соответсвующие поля в таблицы, например: CreateDate datetime, UpdateDate datetime. добавьте дефолтный констрейнт для поля CreateDate со значением GETDATE(), а поле UpdateDate заполняйте значением GETDATE() при каждом обновлении. Примечание: это для MS SQL Server.

Comment: гмм , совсем не понял , можете привести какие-то примеры ? я в интернете ничего не нашел похожего , может не правильно гуглил

Comment: запустите в SSMS в своей базе. CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
 ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
 [Field1] nvarchar(max) NULL,
 [CREATEDATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 [UPDATEDATE] [datetime] NULL
 )
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_CREATEDATE]  DEFAULT (getdate()) FOR [CREATEDATE]
GO
insert into dbo.MyTable (Field1)
values(N'первая строка'), (N'вторая строка'), (N'третья строка');
update dbo.MyTable set Field1 = '2-я строка', UPDATEDATE = getdate() where ID = 2;
select * from dbo.MyTable;

Comment: вы имеете ввиду DatetimePicker  привязать к данным , и вывести это в форму ?

Comment: нет, это всё на уровне базы данных, а отображать уже на форме вы можете как вам хочется